# Dependency Property register names

Tags: wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

```
public string City 
{  
    get { return GetValue(CityProperty).ToString(); }  
    set { SetValue(CityProperty, value); } 
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty CityProperty = 
  DependencyProperty.Register("City", typeof(string), typeof(Object1));
```

If I make a mistake, here:
...Register("**City**"), typeof...

like for instance I forget to capitalize "city", or i.e "vity"

Is the dependency property subsystem just totally blown away? The string City property is still there right? I can set it in various ways and the static CityProperty thingamabob is still there, I can do something somewhere with that.  I can do like Object1.CityProperty and such, But where is exactly is the breakdown/link?  If that "City" literal in the register method and the City property don't match, then the string City property is just not a dependency property?

I guess also I mean, if the string City property is calling GetValue, then what is the difference? Will the subsystem 'find' everything and be able to support using string City property as the: a) target of binding b) animation c) styling

EDIT

In a somewhat disturbing development, the following '*works*' .  When you set the City property from XAML, it apparently stores it somewhere.  What part(s) of a) using as a target for binding, b) styling, c) animation don't  is a mystery to me.

```
namespace util
{
    public class foo : FrameworkElement
    {
        public String City
        {
            get { return (String)GetValue(CityProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CityProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for City.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CityProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("city", typeof(String), typeof(foo), null);
    }
}

namespace screwing_up_dependencies
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var aFoo = this.FindName("bar");
            if (aFoo is util.foo)
            {
                util.foo theFoo = (util.foo)aFoo;
                ((Button)sender).Content = theFoo.City;
            }
        }
    }
}


  <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0"
            xmlns:util="clr-namespace:util"
              >
            <util:foo x:Name="bar" City="blah"></util:foo>
            <Button Content="Button"  Grid.Row="1" Click="Button_Click" Height="105"/>
    </Grid>
```

EDIT 2
Furthermore, you can also do this.  It apparently doesn't make any difference what the "Name" parameter to the register command is.  And also it doesn't seem to matter what the OwnerType parameter is either.

```
<util:foo x:Name="bar2" City="{Binding ElementName=ContentPanel, Path=Width}"></util:foo>

public static readonly DependencyProperty CityProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), typeof(String), typeof(object), null);

var aFoo = this.FindName("bar2");
            if (aFoo is util.foo)
            {
                util.foo theFoo = (util.foo)aFoo;
                ((Button)sender).Content = theFoo.City;
            }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything to find out what happens? Try to set the property in XAML.

Comment: @Clemens See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

> Will the subsystem 'find' everything and be able to support using string City property as the: a) target of binding b) animation c) styling

No.

Reflection is used by other systems to divine information about the instance.  When the property `city` does not exist no operations can occur. For in C# one can have overloaded property names (i.e. `City` and `city`) and those are two separate entities in the eyes of the compiler and the runtime process reflecting off of an unknown instance.

---

> is there any Lint tool available that will detect this kind of thing automagically

To avoid errors when creating dependency properties I use Jeff Wilcox's ([Helpful Silverlight Snippets - Jeff Wilcox](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/02/silverlight-snippets/)). Via using snippets which are geared towards the 6 types of dependency properties, it avoids the errors. Note that even though it is Silverlight, I use them without change in WPF.

Comment: Are you sure 'no operations' can occur? I mean, If I do a Object1.SetValue(Object1.CityProperty, "hello world") and then I do a Object1.Getvalue(Object1.CityProperty) I will get the value back right? AND Upper Case City is still a property of Object1 so I can so <Textblock Text={Binding City}>  So, is it true that Text={Binding City} will get the string from the City Property, which will be calling GetValue(Object1.CityProperty), which in turn will be ?? getting the value internally from the 'city' ?

Comment: I guess what begs, IS, is there any Lint tool available that will detect this kind of thing automagically?  It seems to be an easy place for the un-safe, untyped, string literal to just throw a variable like 'city' into the data-hole, while everything compiles and it seems to work, until you try to use style-inheritance or something and you have NO IDEA WHAT IS GOING ON.

Comment: @AndyzSmith I was speaking in general and it depends on a specific operation. Binding can still happen because you specified `City` and there was a `City` property. But on the other hand a design time operations which need the both to be in sync may fail.

Comment: So, no Lint for existing an existing code base? You would have to have used snippets from day 1 to get the benefit?